# Mongo nested documents read in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, rmongodb

I have a `mongodb` database and I calculated prediction using my mongo documents in R, for this I used the R `rmongodb` library. I can read documents which have a simple key value. However, I don't know how to read nested mongo data in R. Does any one know how to access nested documents in R?

Comment: Can we see structure (`str()`) of your object?

Comment: Did you see [this question & answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003402/queries-in-mongodb/12074341#12074341)?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you wanna read from the BSON structure.

For maps like this {'mapping': {'a':123, 'b':456}}, it's as easy as

```
mongo.bson.value(cval,"mapping.a")
```

or

```
mongo.bson.value(cval,"mapping.b")
```

However, for list structure like this {'list':[1,2,3,4,5]}, you need to use a loops to read them out:

```
for (item in mongo.bson.value(cval,"list")) {
    print(item)
 }
```

You can find the whole example in this tutorial: http://winston.attlin.com/2014/01/building-up-easy-data-analysis-platform.html