# R: How to represent a table augmented by arbitrary key/value pairs for each row?

Tags: r, hash, dataframe

This is a newbie R question. I am beginning to explore the use of R for website analytics. I have a set of page view events which have common properties along with an arbitrary set of properties that depend on the page. For instance, all events will have a `userId`, `createdAt`, and `pageId`, but the `"signup"` page might have a special property `origin` whose value could be `"adwords"` or `"organic"`, etc.

In JSON, the data might look like this:

```
[
   {
      "userId":null,
      "pageId":"home",
      "sessionId":"abcd",
      "createdAt":1381013741,
      "parameters":{},
   },
   {
      "userId":123,
      "pageId":"signup",
      "sessionId":"abcd",
      "createdAt":1381013787,
      "parameters":{
         "origin":"adwords",
         "campaignId":4
      }
   }
]
```

I have been struggling to represent this data in R data structures effectively. **In particular I need to be able to subset the event list by conditions based on the arbitrary key/value pairs,** for instance, select all events whose `pageId=="signup"` and `origin=="adwords"`.

There is enough diversity in the keys used for the arbitrary parameters that it seems unreasonable to create sparsely-populated columns for every possible key.

What I'm currently doing is pre-processing the data into two CSV files, `core_properties.csv` and `parameters.csv`, in the form:

```
# core_properties.csv (one record per pageview)
userId,pageId,sessionId,createdAt
,home,abcd
123,signup,abcd,1381013741
...

# parameters.csv (one record per k/v pair)
row,key,value   # <- "row" here denotes the record index in core_properties.csv
1,origin,adwords
1,campaignId,4
...
```

I then `read.table` each file into a data frame, and I am now attempting to store the k/v pairs a list (with names=keys) inside cells of the core events data frame. This has been a lot of awkward trial and error, and the best approach I've found so far is the following:

```
events <- read.csv('core_properties.csv', header=TRUE)
parameters <- read.csv('parameters.csv',
   header=TRUE,colClasses=c("character","character","character"))
paramLists <- sapply(1:nrow(events), function(x) { list() })
apply(parameters,1,function(x) {
   paramLists [[ as.numeric(x[["row"]]) ]][[ x[["key"]] ]] <<- x[["value"]] })
events$parameters <- paramLists
```

I can now access the origin property of the first event by the syntax: `events[1,][["parameters"]][[1]][["origin"]]` - note it requires for some reason an extra `[[1]]` subscript in there. Data frames do not seem to appreciate being given lists as individual values for cells:

```
> events[1,][["parameters"]] <- list()
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "parameters", value = list()) : 
   replacement has 0 rows, data has 1
```

Is there a best practice for handling this sort of data? I have not found it discussed in the manuals and tutorials.

Thank you!

Comment: JSON translates nicely to `list`s in R.  The names of the list serve as your keys.  For a keyed tabular data structure, have a look at data.table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested lists in R that map nicely to JSON. I have shown a simple example where you filter based on parameter origin.

```
dat <- list(
  list(userId = NULL, pageId = "home", createdAt = 1381013741, parameters = list()),
  list(userId = NULL, pageId = "new", createdAt = 1381013741, parameters = list(origin = 'adwords', campaignId = 4))
)

Filter(function(l){length(l) > 0 && l$parameters$origin == 'adwords'}, dat)
```

Comment: Interesting. But for large sets of data, this use of Filter over a list seems to be a lot slower than the indexing available via data frames: `Filter(function(x){x$pageId=="home"},data)` versus `data[data$page_id=="name",]` - I'm using datasets that are often in the millions of rows and doing a lot of these kinds of filter operations. Do you recommend a different approach for that?

Comment: In that case I would recommend looking into databases like MongoDB which have helper packages that allow you to deal with queries directly from R.

Comment: You will find how to use `rmongodb` to perform advanced queries [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798707/running-advanced-mongodb-queries-in-r-with-rmongodb)